# Direcionar para página com option já selecionado

Tags: html, jquery, css

Preciso que quando o usuário clique em um link ele já direcione para uma página onde tem um select. Até aí tudo bem. O problema é direcionar para essa página e já estar selecionado um dos options.

Por exemplo:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.site.com.br/contato">
  <h5>Não achou o que procurava? Clique aqui!</h5>
</a>
```

Preciso que já direcione para a página contato e esteja selecionado o option "Dúvidas".

```html
<select class="text" id="assunto">
  <option>Selecione o assunto desejado</option>
  <option id="sugestoes" value="1">Fale conosco</option>
  <option id="duvidas" value="2">Dúvidas</option>
  <option id="trabalhe" value="3">Trabalhe conosco</option>
  <option id="clientes" value="4">Cadastro de Clientes</option>
  <option id="revendas" value="5">Cadastro de Revendas</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples basta, vc colocar o atributo **selected** na option que deseja que seja a selecionada.

```html
<select class="text" id="assunto">
  <option>Selecione o assunto desejado</option>
  <option id="sugestoes" value="1">Fale conosco</option>
  <option id="duvidas" value="2" selected>Dúvidas</option>
  <option id="trabalhe" value="3">Trabalhe conosco</option>
  <option id="clientes" value="4">Cadastro de Clientes</option>
  <option id="revendas" value="5">Cadastro de Revendas</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Mas e se agora o cliente queira passar um link para fazer o cadastro de revendas?

Comment: Desculpa Lucas, não entendi a pergunta. Passar um link onde?

Comment: Se o cliente quiser passar um link para o option Cadastro de Revendas. Ele não poderá usar o mesmo link pois vai estar selecionado o option Dúvidas. Mas com base na tua resposta vou fazer de outro formato.
Fazer um if no php e cada vez que a url tiver o id da option ele vai definir o select.